# How to get JSON data from reddit after the first page

Tags: android, json, reddit

So I am currently making an app to work with and learn more about JSON (using GSON) and decided to go with a reddit browsing app.  I am currently able to get the JSON data by using "http://www.reddit.com/.json" and this will get me the JSON for the first 25 posts.  I am trying to get the information for the next posts by using

"http://www.reddit.com/.json?count=25&after=" + name_of_last_post

which name_of_last_post is the name field from my GSON for the last post. This however just brings up the first page's posts again with their numbering starting at 25, I get that the numbering starts at 25 because count is set to 25.  What I am asking is what is the format of the string I can create to get that next set of JSON items.  you can try this your self by going to reddit.com/.json and taking that into a json editor and formatting it nicely than going to the next page of reddit and adding .json before the ?count=25&after=, you will see that the text following after= does not seem to appear on the first JSON file anywhere.  If there are any parts of this question that are still unclear please leave a comment and I will check in on it later.  Thanks and have a great day.

Comment: I swear it was not working but after trying it again it appears to be working.  I am going to try some more test cases quick and make sure that I was not just wrong in going about it somehow.

it does follow the format 

reddit.com/.json?after= + name_of_last_post

you can add count= or limit= if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple of fields that you can use in order to fetch the next page on JSON.

You could either retrieve the 'name' of the last post, or instead of parsing the whole block, you can retrieve the last couple of fields from the JSON that reddit gives you. There are a couple of fields that you can easily use to navigate pages forwards and backwards, they're conveniently called 'after' and 'before'

[image: screenshot of the last few lines of the Json]

Having that value, you can mount your URL with it, which in this case is http://www.reddit.com/.json?count=25&after=t3_3gi42o

This will get you a new JSON, with different 'after' and 'before' fields, pictured below:

[image: screenshot of the last few lines of the Json when using the after query]

Comment: I have no idea what I was doing wrong earlier but this does worrk, I like the format to your answer and I hope that someone else will be able to use this to avoid my frustration.  Thank you :)

Comment: Hey, no problem, I tried to rewrite it in order to make it easier in case someone has the same question you did.